# Securing API between (PHP) web and data servers

Tags: php, security, authentication, ssl

I'm building a client area within a PHP website on **server A** that will send requests to a separate data server **(server B)** asking for raw data relating to a particular client's project.

The system needs to be reasonably secure, but within reason (I need a balance between ease of implementation and security).

This is the first time I've built a system with secure requirements like this, so not sure (a) what that balance should be, and (b) which of the many possible approaches makes sense in the first place.

**Some points:**

- Servers A and B are the only two machines involved (apart from client machine browsing server A, of course)
- Clients must not be able to request data outwith their allocated projects
- The client can specify the project and date range but nothing else
- The connection between servers must be secure to prevent snooping on the data
- The data transfers are one-way -- the web server only sends a request
- The system will be low traffic so request overhead isn't much of a problem -- in the order of a few tens of requests a day

I'm imagining a **REST api** with calls like **/userid/deviceid/daterange** but I'm not clear on how to secure the transmission and prevent clients from accessing other clients' data by working out the URL scheme.

It seems as though **SSL** is an obvious minimum to secure the transfer of the data, but I'm not sure about authentication and silo-ing between users.

**Idea for an approach**

Giving each client a unique key. For each request this is hashed with the request parameters and sent alongside a plaintext version of the request, something like this:

```
 Hash: 202745aff8ed5354f2a8cce94b324afecfad56465cb48d676fd230fa6f2a18f5

 Request params: /123/456/2015010120150714
```

Server B performs a hash the key it has stored and the request parameters, and checks whether this matches what has been sent. If it does, and the user ID, device ID and date range are valid, it responds with the data requested.

The obvious weakness of this approach is the key -- if the copy stored on the web server was to be compromised then anyone could feasibly request data from the data server if they knew the user ID and device IDs. This would be mitigated somewhat by accepting requests only from the web server's IP, but if that was compromised by a malicious script this wouldn't work.

Any suggestions would be helpful. As I said I'm fairly noobian with respect to the security aspects of this so please be gentle!

**EDIT**

Clients log in to the CMS on server A; their credentials aren't needed for the connection between the server A and server B -- the only authentication this question is concerned with is making sure that only server A can communicate with server B, and that communication is secured.

Having thought about it further, would it be enough to do a POST request from the web server in PHP, if SSL handshaking had already taken place?

Comment: Check out OAuth. http://oauth.net/2/

Comment: Use client authentication with certificates for connections between the servers or a tunnel with SSH or VPN.

Comment: I've read a bit on both your ideas, thanks, and added some more to the bottom of the OP.